# Recaptcha V3 is not loading in China

Tags: recaptcha-v3

Recaptcha V3 is not loading in china region but works fine in other regions. Please help

Screenshot from China user's machine.
[From China User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAdSH.png)

Snip from India user (no issue, recaptcha v3 loading properly)
[From India User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9amw.png)

Simple code that is implemented in C#.Net MVC
[MVCView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyqIX.png)
[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31Mco.png)